# Can I use a custom loop for product categories?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to use a custom loop to show Woocommerce categories on a page?

I want to display my Woocommerce categories on the front page and add some classes to the loop.

A sample products loop is here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/sample-products-loop/

I need something like that but to show categories.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, It is possible. The code is something like that:

```
  $elements = get_terms( 'product_cat', array( 'hide_empty' => false ) );

  if( !empty( $elements ) ) {
      foreach( $elements as $element ) {
          $cat = get_term( $element, 'product_cat' );
          echo $cat->name;
      }
  }
```

for getting every single category details use get_term() function. For know more about [get_term()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term). You can fetch all the data and can do anything as per your requirements.

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for.